# Visual Studio Unable to find dependencies for the Setup project

Tags: c#, visual-studio, dependencies, spring-data, setup-project

I have a problem while building a solution that contains a WinForms project, using VS2017 Pro 15.8.6 - my Setup project failed on pre-build validation.

This is the message I get in the Output:

> ------ Starting pre-build validation for project 'Setup' ------ 
>   WARNING: Unable to find dependency 'COMMON.LOGGING' (Signature='AF08829B84F0328E' Version='3.0.0.0') of assembly 'Spring.Services.dll'
>   WARNING: Unable to find dependency 'SPRING.CORE' (Signature='65E474D141E25E07' Version='2.0.1.45000') of assembly 'Spring.Services.dll'
>   WARNING: Unable to find dependency 'COMMON.LOGGING.CORE' (Signature='AF08829B84F0328E' Version='3.0.0.0') of assembly 'Spring.Services.dll'
>   WARNING: Unable to find dependency 'COMMON.LOGGING' (Signature='AF08829B84F0328E' Version='3.0.0.0') of assembly 'Spring.Data.dll'
>   WARNING: Unable to find dependency 'COMMON.LOGGING.CORE' (Signature='AF08829B84F0328E' Version='3.0.0.0') of assembly 'Spring.Data.dll'
>   WARNING: Unable to find dependency 'SPRING.AOP' (Signature='65E474D141E25E07' Version='2.0.1.45000') of assembly 'Spring.Data.dll'
>   WARNING: Unable to find dependency 'SPRING.CORE' (Signature='65E474D141E25E07' Version='2.0.1.45000') of assembly 'Spring.Data.dll'
>   ERROR: An error occurred while validating.  HRESULT = '80131509'
>   ------ Pre-build validation for project 'Setup' completed ------
>   ------ Build started: Project: Setup, Configuration: Debug ------
>   ========== Build: 9 succeeded, 1 failed, 23 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========

Because of it I have no any files at my output folder. I found a solution  "uncheck “Allow parallel project initialization”", but it doesn't work for me.

Comment: VS2017? What type of project do you have? And which version?

Comment: @RuiJarimba VS2017 Pro 15.8.6. WinForms project

Answer (score 1):

For some reason my setup project had multiple instances of System.ValueTuple.dll:

[image: tuplemania]

Deleting the extras at the bottom made the setup project build. For one of them I had to right click, choose "Find In Editor", and delete from the resulting window.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem was , that i mixed up the build config(from visual studio) and the 'primary project output'(of the setup project).

I resetup the 'primery output'of the project and checked if my config 'Release| Any Cpu' fits the setup 'project output'

[setup prj primery output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rbo2K.png)

[visual studio config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KJUwP.png)